# How Define Counter Inside Parallel.Foreach And Stop That Loop In A Specific Number

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, console-application, parallel.foreach

How Can I Define Counter Inside Parallel.Foreach And **Stop That Loot In A Specific Number**?
I asked this Question because that counter inside Parallel.ForEach does not work in a regular action.
please see this little example :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int Count_Step = -1;
    string[] lines = new string[] 
    { 
        "0",
        "1",
        "2",
        "3",
        "4",
        "5",
        "6",
        "7",
        "8",
        "9",
        "10",
        "11",
        "12",
        "13",
        "14",
        "15",
        "16",
        "17",
        "18",
        "19"
    };

    List<string> list_lines = new List<string>(lines);

    ParallelOptions parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions();
    parallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3;

    Parallel.ForEach(list_lines, parallelOptions, (line, state, index) =>
    {
        if (Count_Step == 10)
            state.Stop();
        Count_Step++;
        Console.WriteLine(index + " : " + line + " : " + Count_Step);
        //Thread.Sleep(5000);
    });

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

i want 10 lines in output, not more!
how can i do that?

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to only process the first 10 items in the list in parallel, or do you only want to process any 10 items in parallel then stop after you have done 10?

Comment: any 10 items in parallel then stop after you have done 10

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you only want to output 10 lines do this instead,

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var lines = new List<string> 
    { 
        "0",
        "1",
        "2",
        "3",
        "4",
        "5",
        "6",
        "7",
        "8",
        "9",
        ...
    };

    var parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions
        {        
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3
        };

    Parallel.ForEach(lines.Take(10), parallelOptions, (line, index) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", index, line);
        ////Thread.Sleep(5000);
    });

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

alternatively

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var lines = new List<string> 
    { 
        "0",
        "1",
        "2",
        "3",
        "4",
        "5",
        "6",
        "7",
        "8",
        "9",
        ...
    };

    var parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions
        {        
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3
        };

    Parallel.For(0, 9, parallelOptions, i =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", i, lines[i]);
        ////Thread.Sleep(5000);
    });

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

or even

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var lines = new List<string> 
    { 
        "0",
        "1",
        "2",
        "3",
        "4",
        "5",
        "6",
        "7",
        "8",
        "9",
        ...
    };

    Enumerable.Range(0, 10).AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(3).ForAll(i =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", i, lines[i]);
        ////Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

---

If you really want your parallel iterations to update some value outside the loop, then you will need to ensure all updates and reads of the changing variable are thread-safe.

If you are incrementing an integer you could do it like this.

```
var stepCount = 0;

Enumerable.Range(0, 10).AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(3).ForAll(i =>
    {
        var thisCount = Interlocked.Increment(ref stepCount);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1} : {2}", i, lines[i], thisCount);
        ////Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }

Console.ReadLine();
```

However, the output of `thisCount` is not garaunteed to be contiguous in the console window, there could be a thread switch between the two lines.

If you want to do somthing more sophisticated, like cancelling the processing part way through you should take a look at [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx).

Comment: we can not change that array :) this is just an example as i said in my Q. i want it for other situations.

Comment: thanks for the edit. but i will get that 9 Number inside for(in other situation) -> what can i do about that?

Comment: @MoonLight I don't understand, what do you mean by "that 9 Number", are you referring to `Count_Step`?

Comment: @MoonLight I've added an example with an external counter.

Comment: How do you translate the (line, index) to VB in? Parallel.ForEach(lines.Take(10), parallelOptions, (line, index) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", index, line);
        ////Thread.Sleep(5000);
    });

Answer (score 4):

Try `Parallel.For()`

[Parallel.For Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782869.aspx)